Obtaining newly added rows' IDs from one table and duplicating existing rows with these new IDs in another table
I have two tables A and B.
A looks like this:
ID | Name | Designation
B looks like this:
ID | Department
When adding rows in A, the ID is generated automatically using a sequence. After rows are added in A rows must be added to B, with the same A's newly generated IDs in B's ID field and the Department value must be duplicated from the row above. Lets say 5 rows are added in A, then the same number of rows which is 5 must be added in B with A's newly generated 5 IDs and with the Department column value duplicated for all the 5 rows with an already existing row above.
What is the SQL query for the same?
Note: I know that for this example, these two tables should have been combined to one but these here are sample tables used to portray the same blocker at work. So I can't redesign the tables.

Please review [mre] and update the post with actual DDL, sample data, and expected results. Also describe/show what you have already tried.

With these table definitions:
CREATE TABLE a (
  id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  designation TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a (id),
  department INTEGER NOT NULL
);

the following SQL demonstrates an approach for capturing rows  inserted into a and using those to insert into b:
WITH
  new_rows AS (
    INSERT INTO a(name, designation)
    SELECT 'A' || gs.n, 'Designation ' || gs.n
      FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 5) gs(n)
    RETURNING *
  )
INSERT INTO b(id, department)
SELECT id, 10
  FROM new_rows;

After executing, tables a and b have the following content:
Table A:



id
name
designation




1
A1
Designation 1


2
A2
Designation 2


3
A3
Designation 3


4
A4
Designation 4


5
A5
Designation 5



Table B:



id
department




1
1


2
1


3
1


4
1


5
1



Instead of capturing the entire row, it's also possible to return only the columns needed for inserting into the second table; e.g., RETURNING id INSTEAD OF RETURNING *.
